# Why my jquery doesn't work on different domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have same code on 2 different websites, 1 is working fine and other one looks like it is not doing jquery functions

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"> 
     <title>jQuery Countdown</title> 
     <link rel="stylesheet" href=/build/timer/css/jquery.countdown.css">
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>      
     <script src="/build/timer/js/jquery.plugin.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/build/timer/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script> 
     <script> 
       var j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
       j(function () {  
         var austDay = new Date();  
         austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);  
         j('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});    
         j('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear()); }); 
     </script> 
     <style>
       #defaultCountdown {margin-left: -380px;width: 740px;height: 65px;}
       #defaultCountdown span {font-size: 30px;font-family: Arial;} 
        body {background: #0f0017;} 
     </style> 
   </head> 
<body>

  <div id="defaultCountdown"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

here is my code..

here is a working link: http://signalsindicator.com/timer/index.html
here is not working one: https://traders.institute/build/timer/index.html

what may be causing this problem, it is same code on both of them?

Comment: On one page you using without no conflict which is working fine but on other you are trying to use no conflict aliasing, which seems to be not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second link you postet is https, so you have to load the scripts with https as well.

Answer (score 0):

> What may be causing this problem, it is same code on both of them?

The answer: Mixed content issue.

A Mixed content occurs when initial HTML is loaded over a secure HTTPS connection, but other resources (such as images, videos, stylesheets, scripts) are loaded over an insecure HTTP connection.

*... More details [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content).*

Answer (score -1):

Also missing the opening quotes around the stylesheet.

href="/build/timer/css/jquery.countdown.css">